# NSKeyedArchiver would not save or load objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding, nskeyedunarchiver

So I have an array with some custom classes:

NSMutableArray With Games (FirstViewcontroller)
-Game with Dices (Game.m)
-- Dices With Options (Dices.m)

In each custom class i've setter the encode and decode up:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:[self _gameNaam] forKey:@"_gameNaam"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;
    [self set_gameNaam:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"_gameNaam"]];

    return self;
}
```

And in the first view controller I am handeling the loading and saving. But the decoder always returns null of no array. So nothing inside of it. Here is my code:

```
- (void) saveToFile{
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *bestand = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.kets"];

    if ([NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[self dobbelArray] toFile:bestand])
        NSLog(@"Did it!!");
}

- (void) loadFromFile{

    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *bestand = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.kets"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bestand]){
        if ([NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:bestand])
            NSLog(@"Did it!!");
    }
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:[self dobbelArray] forKey:@"dobbelArray"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (!(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
        return nil;

    [self setDobbelArray:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dobbelArray"]];

    return self;
}
```

Not sure of what i'm doing wrong? The loading is called in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` FirstViewController. After the `[NSMutableArray new];` of my array. Saving is done when going back grom an `UnwindSegue` from my addViewController.

Any idea's?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unarchiveObjectWithFile:` returns the unarchived object for you to use. At the moment you just check if it is nil (with your `if` statement) and then it gets destroyed (deallocated because you don't use it, assuming you're using ARC).

So, get the object returned by `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` and set it to your property.

Not sure what you're trying to do with NSCoding on the view controller, but it may well not do what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh yeah, needed to set the object from the unarchiver.. And the NSCoding is there for my custom classes? Or doesn't i need to use it for this ?

Comment: You will generally load the view controller from a NIB / storyboard, so it is already unarchived and without your custom data. You should just load your data from 'file' when the controller is created / first used as you do in `loadFromFile`...